# Gitlab runner fails with connection timeout

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have gitlab runner with, `docker` as executor and `docker:latest` as default image.

Runner is connected to the project and runs pipeline, but it stuck at

> Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/sachith/omy-project/.git/
>
> fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.myhost.com:1234/sachith/omy-project.git/': Failed to connect to gitlab.myhost.com port 1234: Operation timed out

I logged to gitlab-runner running server and tried cloning project as `gitlab-runner` user and it worked.

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple mistake I made when I register `gitlab-runner`. I just used `gitlab-runner register [options]`

But when I register it with `sudo`, it was working properly.

`sudo gitlab-runner register [option]`

Runner is running in `Ubuntu-18.04` server.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely because your requests were dropped before they landed on the GitLab host. Check your firewalls and other security rules after assured that the 1234 port is open

Comment: Port is open and can access to it. Will check and let you know.